# Receiving "Input Variables Exceeded 1000" error even after updating max_input_vars

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, magento, apache2

I'm running Magento, and I am receiving "mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  Unknown: Input variables exceeded 1000. To increase the limit change max_input_vars in php.ini. in Unknown on line 0" when trying to save Related Products with 5000+ products in the DB.

Most people recommend trying to fix this by updating the max_input_vars to something higher. I went ahead and added max_input_vars = 100000 to php.ini, and added php_value max_input_vars 100000 to .htaccess for good measure.

php.ini is being updated, when I run php -i | grep max_input_vars it outputs max_input_vars => 100000 => 100000

I also tried smaller numbers like 5000, 6000 (in case for some reason 100000 is too high)

I did remember to restart apache2, so that is not the issue.

No matter what I do, I still receive "mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  Unknown: Input variables exceeded 1000. To increase the limit change max_input_vars in php.ini. in Unknown on line 0"

Any ideas?

Comment: checking `php -i` is pointless. that's the command line version, which has a different .ini file than the SAPI (in-webserver) version. YOu need to run phpinfo() inside a web-based script, preferably calling the function as close as possible to where you're getting the error.

Comment: Sure enough, it was loading php.ini from somewhere else. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

create a pi.php file with just the code:

```
<?php phpinfo();
```

in it and save it in the same folder as your Magento, then access via browser.

The value that will be displayed for max_input_vars (local column) is your run-time value. If it differs from your setting in php.ini, you're probably changing the wrong INI file.

Mod_FCGID can use a differenct file from the "classic" /etc/php.ini, or settings in any of the files in /etc/php.d/ - for instance - may override the ones in the "global file".

phpinfo() shows the list of parsed INI files, so you can see which to amend.

**PLEASE** remember to take off the file once you have fixed the issue: it's a likely security threat, as you show a lot of details that may be useful to hackers.

Answer (score 0):

The problem arises from your Ajax XMLHttpRequest() function.

You are trying to send FormData information through XHttp.send(FormData) using wrong header.

In your ajax function erase any line of .setRequestHeader. E.g

```
XHttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
```

erase that. It will be set to the proper headers by default.